# Ollydbg Instructions Are Splitted

Tags: ollydbg, x86, anti-debugging

When I am trying to reverse ZeroAccess rootkit, ollydbg shows instructions as seperated like;

it should be e874010000 as a single instruction which is a call to some routine but it shows them like the picture above,

[image]

before the EIP jumps shown place there are instructions which are below,

[image]

I think int 2Dh (anti debug) is probably related to this situation. Can somebody enlighten me ? Or show some source to read and learn what is exactly going on here ?

OK I have managed to solve this problem by clicking right, then Analysis then Remove object scan for module. I think Olly is misinterpreted the code for some reason, even if I did not understand why this solved my problem. Anyway If there is somebody to explain why Olly did this, is welcomed.

Comment: There is a good answer here: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1541/int-2d-anti-forensic-method/1544#1544

Comment: I have read this post before I post my question. But my problem is consistent. When I open the program and not run yet, Ollydbg still could not give correct instructions, If my problem was related to that post I should have faced this when the program is running, am I wrong ?? Also I have opened program with static analysis tool other than ollydbg it shows all instructions clearly.

Comment: A lot of things happen before Olly stops execution, maybe the antidebugging code runs in a TLS-callback or alike.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INT 2D Anti-Forensic Method](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1541/int-2d-anti-forensic-method)