# What is the reason for INT 0x2D byte scission?

Tags: anti-debugging

What is the reason behind the byte scission (the next immediate byte following "int 2d" is skipped) behaviour when executing INT 0x2D?
I came across this article http://www.drdobbs.com/monitoring-nt-debug-services/184416239 but still cannot understand what is the reason for Windows to skip the byte.
Any explanation is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: The DrDobbs article does not mention 'byte scission' at all, which seems to be a term [invented by Dr Fu](http://fumalwareanalysis.blogspot.de/2011/09/malware-analysis-3-int2d-anti-debugging.html) in relation to a peculiarity/quirk in Windows (see [Peter Ferrie's paper](http://pferrie.tripod.com/papers/unpackers23.pdf) which explains it in detail).

Comment: Thanks! That answer the question. Yeah, I know that the Dr Dobbs article didn't not mention "byte scission".  That is the only article I came across after searching for mechanism behind INT 0x2D after reading about it on Dr Fu's blog.  The other articles on the net usually only mention that a byte will be skipped without explanation.  Hence this question. Thanks for pointing me to Peter Ferrie's paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full details of the behavior are described here:
http://pferrie.epizy.com/papers/antidebug.pdf

Specifically, if the EAX register has the value of 1, 3, or 4 on all versions of Windows, or the value 5 on Windows Vista and later, then Windows will increase by one the exception address.  Finally, it issues an EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT (0x80000003) exception if a debugger is present.

The skipped byte is intended to pass information to the kernel-mode component, but the mechanism is not used by default.

Comment: Thanks. When you say the skipped byte is intended to pass information to kernel-mode component, specifically what information? Is it an undocumented feature of Windows kernel? I am still puzzle why do INT 0x2D need to behave the way it does. Comparatively the behaviour of INT 3 seem more understandable.

Comment: you can pass any single-byte value to the kernel, as a "parameter" to the interrupt, along with register values.  This is not possible using int 3 style.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it’s because the `int 0x2d` instruction is supposed to be immediately followed by a `int3` breakpoint opcode, which in turn is presumably a graceful degradation/backwards compatibility feature.

Interrupt 0x2d is a debugger hook, used to pass information from the debugged program to the debugger; presumably the ultimate place where APIs like [`DbgPrintEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-dbgprintex) are implemented.  A debugger that traps interrupt 0x2d will respond to the hook invocation, skip the `int3` opcode that follows, and resume execution normally.  A more primitive debugger that ignores interrupt 0x2d will instead trap the `int3` opcode, allowing the user to examine register state and respond to the hook call manually; or to patch a `nop` instruction over the breakpoint opcode to ignore the hook from now on.

If you disassemble BOOTMGR.EXE (the PE executable extracted from BOOTMGR), MEMTEST.EXE, WINLOAD.EXE or NTOSKRNL.EXE, you will see the `int 0x2d` / `int3` sequence appear.  Those are boot-time and/or kernel-mode programs which execute in a different environment from normal Windows applications, but the debugger ABI they are subject to is presumably the same.